# iOS 64Bit converting dont work in a method with va_list

Tags: ios, 64-bit, variadic-functions

I am trying to make an iOS-app ready for 64bit. 
I got a method which build me a string with entries from an enum. The parameters from this method can be variable in count.
The method works fine under 32bit, but under 64bit my for-loop cant end correctly.

Here some code from .h:

```
#define enumToString(intVal) \
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", intVal]

#define ENUM_END -1

typedef enum _MYENTRIES
{
    entry1,
    entry2,
    entry3
}  MYENTRIES;
typedef NSUInteger MYENTRY;
```

My crashing method: (the loop has to end, but it doesn't end)

```
-(NSString*) getMyString:(MYENTRY) firstArg, ...  {
   va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);

   NSMutableString *mySTRING = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];

   for (MYENTRY arg = firstArg; arg != ENUM_END; arg = va_arg(args, MYENTRY))
    {
        NSLog(@"arg: %d %@", arg, enumToString(arg)); // when ENUM_END: "arg: -1 4294967295"
        [mySTRING appendString:self.myDictionary[[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", arg]]];
    }
```

An example methodcall:

```
myString = [myClass getMyString: entry1, entry3, ENUM_END , nil];
```

Hope you can help me.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

That's because MYENTRIES and MYENTRY are different types. One is 32 bit, and the other is 64 bit. Passing 32 bit values and reading them as 64 bit isn't going to work.

That's what the NS_ENUM macro is there for. Google for it, understand it, and use it. You will also have the problem that ENUM_END is not the same type as either MYENTRIES or MYENTRY (it is an int). Unless you can quote the rules for type conversion between int and unsigned long by heart (which you can't), I suggest you make it part of the enum.